Error while evaluating property 'packageOverride' of task ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:processReleaseManifest'
Getting an error while generating release apk
I have tried these solution's

changed kotlin version from 1.6.2. to 1.8.0
Uninstall the library(react-native-community_datetimepicker) but still getting the issue
Update gradle version from 6.9 to 7.2

System configuration

Android studio version - Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch
Java version - 11
macOS - sonoma 14.4
Processor - i7

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:processReleaseManifest'.
> Error while evaluating property 'packageOverride' of task ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:processReleaseManifest'
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:processReleaseManifest' property 'packageOverride'.
      > Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
         > Package Name not found in /Users/apple/Desktop/projects/kliq/node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1"
             kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"

    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
             classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

Package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation": "^0.6.3",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^9.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.12",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.5.1",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.2.2",
    "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^8.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1291.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-device-country": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-face-pile": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.4",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-in-app-notification": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "3.0.0",
    "react-native-popover": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.14.0",
    "react-native-slider-custom": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "rn-select-date-range": "^3.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  }

